# How to check two values of text box using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have used ***document.getElementByID("textboxname").value*** to compare but *it* checks character by character as it considers integer value a string value.

I like to know how to convert   ***document.getElementByID("textboxname").value*** string notation to integer notation so that it will be easy to compare integer values.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use parseInt("your string") to convert it into valid integer

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt(document.getElementByID("textboxname").value, 10);`